# Display i18n message on button.onclick attribute

Tags: thymeleaf

How should I display a Thymeleaf i18n messages on the code below:

```
<button th:text="#{msg_warning}" onclick="return confirm("[[#{msg_confirm_warning}]]")">
    Delete
</button>
```

Even using `th:attr`

```
<button th:text="#{msg_warning}" th:attr="onclick='return confirm(\'#{msg_confirm_warning}\');'">
    Delete
</button>
```

The output should be the string value of `msg_confirm_warning` whenever the button is clicked. But it displays `[[#{msg_confirm_warning}]]` string instead.

Comment: Try to use `th:attr`.

Comment: I've tried to use `th:attr` is still display the same message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well I guess I made the wrong syntax. With the code below, it solved my problem.

```
<button th:text="#{msg_warning}" th:attr="onclick='return confirm(\'' + #{msg_confirm_warning} + '\');'">
    Delete
</button>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!